# Why am I not able to release my gem to github?

Tags: git, github, rubygems

I am using jeweler to publish a gem.  I am at the point of releasing the gem to github, and this is happening:

```
$ sudo rake release
Password:
(in /Users/***/code/testgem)
Pushing master to origin
rake aborted!
git push "origin" "master"  2>&1:Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have verified that my SSH keys are connected to github properly:

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
[lots of stuff]

Hi *****! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2384, received 2888 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 37829.8, received 45827.4
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this before I'd finished typing out the question :)

"rake release" does not work with sudo.